# what does invalid double null mean?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: What can be a reason for that?]

What can be the reason?Which double value can be null I can not detect...

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:driver/Components/commonwidget.dart';
import 'package:driver/Components/custom_button.dart';
import 'package:driver/Locale/locales.dart';
import 'package:driver/Theme/colors.dart';
import 'package:driver/baseurl/baseurlg.dart';
import 'package:driver/beanmodel/orderhistory.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:toast/toast.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class OrderAcceptedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OrderAcceptedPageState createState() => _OrderAcceptedPageState();
}

class _OrderAcceptedPageState extends State<OrderAcceptedPage> {
  OrderHistory? orderDetaials;
  bool enterFirst = false;
  bool isLoading = false;
  dynamic distance;
  dynamic time;
  double? lat;
  double? lng;
  var http = Client();

  double calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var c = cos;
    var a = 0.5 -
        c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
        c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
  }

  String calculateTime(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    double kms = calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
    double kmsPerMin = 0.5;
    double minsTaken = kms / kmsPerMin;
    double min = minsTaken;
    if (min < 60) {
      return "" + '${min.toInt()}' + " mins";
    } else {
      double tt = min % 60;
      String minutes = '${tt.toInt()}';
      minutes = minutes.length == 1 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      return '${(min.toInt() / 60).toStringAsFixed(2)}' +
          " hour " +
          minutes +
          " mins";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var locale = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
    Map<String, dynamic>? dataReced =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>?;
    if (!enterFirst) {
      setState(() {
        enterFirst = true;
        orderDetaials = dataReced!['OrderDetail'];
        distance = calculateDistance(
                double.parse('${orderDetaials!.userLat ?? 1}'),
                double.parse('${orderDetaials!.userLng ?? 1}'),
                double.parse('${orderDetaials!.storeLat ?? 1}'),
                double.parse('${orderDetaials!.storeLng ?? 1}'))
            .toStringAsFixed(2);
        time = calculateTime(
            double.parse('${orderDetaials!.userLat}'),
            double.parse('${orderDetaials!.userLng}'),
            double.parse('${orderDetaials!.storeLat}'),
            double.parse('${orderDetaials!.storeLng}'));
        print('$distance');
        print('$time');
      });
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60),
        child: AppBar(
          title: Text('${locale.order} - #${orderDetaials!.cartId}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4!.copyWith(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: kMainTextColor,
                  fontSize: 13)),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          actions: [
            buildCircularButton(
                context, Icons.shopping_basket, locale.itemInfo!,
                details: orderDetaials!.items, type: 1),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'assets/Acceptedmap.png',
            width: 500,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      locale.distance!,
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .bodyText1!
                          .copyWith(fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                    subtitle: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(
                            text: '$distance km ',
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .bodyText1!
                                .copyWith(color: Colors.green)),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: '($time)',
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .subtitle2!
                                .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                      ]),
                    ),
                    trailing: buildCircularButton(
                        context, Icons.navigation, locale.direction!,
                        type: 2,
                        url:
                            'https://waze.com/ul?ll=${orderDetaials!.userLat},${orderDetaials!.userLng}'),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.location_on,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      '${orderDetaials!.storeName}',
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .subtitle1!
                          .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      '${orderDetaials!.storeAddress}',
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .bodyText2!
                          .copyWith(fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.navigation,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      '${orderDetaials!.userName}',
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .subtitle1!
                          .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      '${orderDetaials!.userAddress}',
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .bodyText2!
                          .copyWith(fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.call,
                          color: Theme.of(context).focusColor,
                          size: 18,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _launchURL("tel:${orderDetaials!.userPhone}");
                        }),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.comment,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      //'${orderDetaials!.storeName}',
                      '${locale.orderNote}',
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .subtitle1!
                          .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      '${orderDetaials!.orderNotes}',
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .bodyText2!
                          .copyWith(fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                  ),
                  isLoading
                      ? Container(
                          height: 60,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Align(
                            heightFactor: 40,
                            widthFactor: 40,
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          ),
                        )
                      : CustomButton(
                          onTap: () async {
                            if (!isLoading) {
                              setState(() {
                                isLoading = true;
                              });

                              outForDelivery(context, orderDetaials!.cartId);
                            }
                          },
                          label: locale.acceptDelivery,
                        ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void outForDelivery(BuildContext context, dynamic cartid) async {
    http.post(outForDeliveryUri, body: {'cart_id': '$cartid'}).then(
        (value) async {
      print(value.body);
      var js = jsonDecode(value.body);
      if ('${js['status']}' == '1') {
        Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
      }
      ToastContext().init(context);
      Toast.show(js['message'],
          duration: Toast.lengthShort, gravity: Toast.center);
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  _launchURL(url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}
```

Here you can see codes.Error comes from this code.I can not detect which value can be null.......
After reviewing the code please say possible problem that can cause this error............................................................

Comment: can you add the code which is causing this error

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you use `double.parse` with an invalid string format. Most likely you are passing `null` value into that variable.

Comment: Sir I added a code could you please look at the code?

Comment: Based on the error you are getting, the line 67 is causing the issue. ```double.parse('${orderDetaials!.userLat ?? 1}'); ```. Try to print the value ```orderDetaials!.userLat``` to see what is it holding.

Comment: it did not help    value is not null

Comment: What is the value? might be a string that you can't convert to double.